# Financial market with two stocks of same volatility but different rates

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

Does the existence of two independent stocks
$$
dX_1=r_1X_1 dt+ \sigma dW_1
$$

$$
dX_2=r_2X_2 dt+\sigma dW_2
$$
with $r_1\gg r_2$, $\sigma>0$ and independent Brownian motions $W_1,W_2$ contradict any common market axiom? In particular, in the case $r_1>r_2+\mu$ where $\mu$ is the interest rate of a bond, I would expect that such a market cannot exist in reality, since I cannot imagine anyone being interested in selling $X_1$ to buy $X_2$ in such a market.

If we had $W_1=W_2$ then an arbitrage opportunity existed, so the two stocks could indeed not coexist in realistic markets. However, I don't know if the same intuition transfers to the case of independent Brownian motions.

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect that such a market cannot exist in reality

"In reality" there is no Wiener processes, nor geometric Brownian motions, neither independence.

I suspect that by "realistic" market you mean arbitrage-free. Then yes, this model *is* realistic as it is arbitrage-free *in the usual sense*.
Denoting $r$ the risk-free interest rate, the martingale measure on $[0,T]$ is given by 
$$
\frac{d\mathrm{P}^*}{d\mathrm{P}} = \exp\left\{ \frac{(r-r_1)W_1(T)+(r-r_2)W_2(T)}{\sigma} -\frac{(r-r_1)^2 + (r-r_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}T \right\}.
$$

Comment: Absence of arbitrage is a necessary but maybe not a sufficient property of what I called "realistic market". Let's say that I meant a market that can / coule be observed (in approximation, please don't get nitpicking about this) in reality. Whether absence of arbitrage is already sufficient for this is actually the very core of my question and I would be happy even about nonrigorous thoughts and insights about this

Comment: It's not nitpicking, I'm exactly trying to grasp what do you mean by "realistic". "Can be observed in approximation to reality" - what do you mean by this? You can update your question with more detail.

Comment: I certainly don't mean to talk about whether stochastic processes exist in reality. I mean "realistic" just as it is meant in "a market with arbitrage opportunities is unrealistic". Basically, my question is whether there exists a property X!=ExistenceOfArbitrageOpportunities such that we also have "a market with property X is unrealistic". And my gut feeling was that the property of having two stocks one of which is clearly better is such a property. I am aware that such a market does not have an arbitrage opportunity but I was wondering if it is still unrealistic for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to understand me though. I am aware that I am not asking a clear cut question

Comment: Without a clear question, it is very unlikely that you'll get an answer here. Try **[QF.SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)**

Comment: You don't think the question whether markets as the one described in my question describe realistic markets suits math.se? I think also as a mathematician you should first think about the meaning of your subject before you start analyzing it, even if this first step cannot be done at the rigor one is accustomed to. See the article "What is  ... a Free Lunch?" by Schachermayer that was published in the Notices of the American Mathematical Society

Comment: 1. I can't tell whether the question suits math.se or not, as I still don't see a question here, sorry. 2. What place in Schachermayer's article you are referring to? What you're trying to tell?

Comment: It's fine, I'll try qf.se